# MySQL query very slow on group by and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following tables:

hospitals (~28K rows), 
inspections (~116K rows), 
issues (~290K rows)

Hospitals have inspections and each inspection has zero or more issues. I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, BName, BCity, BAddress, BState, BZip, Ins_date, BCountry, Ins_Type
FROM ( SELECT b.id as ID, b.hospital_name as BName, b.city as BCity, b.address as BAddress, b.country as BCountry, b.state as BState, b.zip as 
BPostal, i.date as Ins_date, v.type as Ins_Type
FROM hospital_table b, inspection_table i, issue_table v
WHERE b.id = i.business_id
    AND i.id = v.inspection_id
    ORDER BY b.hospital_name, i.date DESC ) AS sumissues
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

The output I expect and get is:

```
112 | Burnaby Memorial | Burnaby | 3935 Kincaid St | BC | 2017-07-19 | Canada | Cleanliness
```

The problem is it takes about 40seconds to run. I have an index on the foreign keys, and inspection_table.date. Any ideas on how I can optimize this?

Comment: Why Order by in inner query `ORDER BY b.hospital_name, i.date DESC` ?? I think this is unnecessary. just remove it and try it again.

Comment: What are you trying to count? Thenumebr of inspections per day? The number of issues per hospital? Something else?  Do you expect one row per hospital as the output?  Your question is sufficiently detailed to provide adeginitive answer.

Comment: Can you run an explain with your query and post results that will help give a better answer. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code

The order by in subselect not needed  and also the subselect is not needed

```
SELECT 
     count(*) as count
    , b.hospital_name as BName
    , b.city as BCity
    , b.address as BAddress
    , b.country as BCountry
    , b.state as BState
    , b.zip as BPostal
    , i.date as Ins_date
    , v.type as Ins_Type
FROM hospital_table b
INNER JOIN inspection_table i ON b.id = i.business_id
INNER JOIN  issue_table v ON i.id = v.inspection_id
GROUP BY b.id 
ORDER BY count DESC, b.hospital_name, i.date
```

But be careful for what in commente   by @User_by_Already

for this and for avoi more rows  group for the others column and if you don'care for the result of these columns you can use (fake) aggregation function

```
SELECT 
     count(*) as count
    , b.hospital_name as BName
    , b.city as BCity
    , b.address as BAddress
    , b.country as BCountry
    , b.state as BState
    , b.zip as BPostal
    , min(i.date) as Ins_date
    , min(v.type) as Ins_Type
FROM hospital_table b
INNER JOIN inspection_table i ON b.id = i.business_id
INNER JOIN  issue_table v ON i.id = v.inspection_id
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY count DESC, b.hospital_name, i.date
```

Comment: Grouping by only one column, but outputting many more than that, might work in older versions of MySQL but it is always bad practice. Introducing columns i.date and v.vtype should produce many more than one row per b.id

Comment: @Used_By_Already   correct i was  updating with this too .. but yoru comment si more faster ..

Comment: . answer  updated  with a suggetion for group by  and columns

Comment: Please be careful as of MySQL 5.7 onward the default behaviour of GROUP BY changes and neither query above would be valid see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by  ao **ALL** non-aggregating columns need to be specified in the group by clause. I don't know what should happen with  **i.date and v.vtype** because it isn't clear from the question what should be counted.

Comment: As per the example in my question, the number of violations by type need to be counted. The ORDER BY date is required because I want to know the last time the hospital was inspected where the issue type was observed.

Comment: In your code the order by inside the is unuseful for the final result and  slow the query  .. you can add the order by you need  in the outer query  .. .. anyway i have update the answer  with the order by  too .. otherwise add  a proper data sample to your question and the expcted result